# how to switching scenes in javafx (NO FXML)

Tags: java, javafx, illegalargumentexception

I ask for your understanding, I am a beginner;)

I'm trying to build a simple application using JavaFX. The problem is that when I open the window the first time it goes well, but if I want to change the scene it throws an error...

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   AnchorPane@1809546[styleClass=root]is already set as root of another
>   scene#

Main class

```java
public class Main extends Application{

    //private Stage primaryStage;

    @Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Login login = new Login();
    Scene scene = login.okno();



    primaryStage.setTitle("Komunikator sieciowy JAVA");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();

}

    //public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
    //  return this.primaryStage;
    //}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Login

```java
public class Login {
    private GridPane grid;
    private Scene scene;
    private Text title;
    private Label nick;
    private Button wejdzBtn;
    private TextField userName;
    //private Alert oknoDlg;




    public Login()  {
        grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment (Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(25,25,25,25));
        scene = new Scene (grid, 300, 150);
        utworzBtn();
        utworzLogin();
        utworzTekst();
        utworzNick();
        //oknoDialogowe();


    }

    //private void oknoDialogowe()  {
        //Alert oknoDlg = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        //oknoDlg.setTitle("Informacja");
        //oknoDlg.setContentText("test");  
    //  oknoDlg.setHeaderText(null);
        //oknoDlg.showAndWait();


    //}

    private void utworzBtn() {
        wejdzBtn = new Button("Zaloguj si\u0119");
        HBox hbBtn = new HBox(10);
        hbBtn.setAlignment (Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        hbBtn.getChildren().add(wejdzBtn);
        grid.add(hbBtn, 1, 2);
        //wejdzBtn.setDisable(true);
        wejdzBtn.setOnAction(e -> {
            Messages mess = new Messages();
            grid.getScene().setRoot(mess.messa());;
        });

    }

    private void utworzLogin() {

        nick = new Label("Nick:");
        grid.add(nick, 0, 1);
    }

    private void utworzNick() {
        userName = new TextField();
        grid.add(userName,1,1);
        // informacja w polu tekstowym
        userName.setPromptText("Max 15 znak\u00f3w");
        userName.setFocusTraversable(false);

        //maksymalna ilość znaków
        final int maxLength = 15;
        userName.setOnKeyTyped(t -> {
            if (userName.getText().length() > maxLength)
            {
                int pos = userName.getCaretPosition();
                userName.setText(userName.getText(0, maxLength));
                userName.positionCaret(pos);
            }
        });

    }

    private void utworzTekst() {
        title = new Text ("Dzień dobry!");
        title.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
        grid.add(title, 0, 0, 2, 1);
    }

    public Scene okno() {
        return scene;
    }


}
```

and and a little another class that I'm trying to change with button from login.java

```java
    public class Messages {
    private AnchorPane anchor;
    private Scene scena;
    //private Label nick;
    private Button sendBtn;
    private TextField poleDoWpisywania;
    private TextArea poleDoWyswietlania, pobierzNick;


    public Messages() {

        anchor = new AnchorPane();
        scena = new Scene(anchor, 700, 600);
        pobierzNick();
        poleDoWpisywania();
        poleDoWyswietlania();
        utworzPrzycisk();

}
    private void utworzPrzycisk() {
        sendBtn = new Button("Wy\u015Blij");
        sendBtn.setDisable(true);

    }

    private void pobierzNick(){
        pobierzNick = new TextArea();
        pobierzNick.setEditable(false);
        pobierzNick.setWrapText(true);
}

    private void poleDoWpisywania() {
    poleDoWpisywania = new TextField();


}

    private void poleDoWyswietlania() {
        poleDoWyswietlania = new TextArea();
        poleDoWyswietlania.setEditable(false);
        poleDoWyswietlania.setWrapText(true);


}


    public Pane messa() {
        return anchor;
}
    }
```

could I ask you to  show the right way to fix the bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX defines a scene graph which is a tree data structure that has a single root node. For your application (i.e. the code you posted), the root node is the `primaryStage` (this is the parameter in method `start()` in class `Main`). The `primaryStage` can have several `Scene`s. Each `Scene` must have its own root node.

The error message you are getting means that a `Scene`'s root cannot also be the root of another `Scene`. In other words `anchor` is the root for `scena` in class `Messages` which means it can't be set as the root for `scene` in class `Login`.

Apart from that, if you want to change `Scene`'s you need to call method `setScene()` of class `Stage`. Here is your `Login` class and `Messages` class with changes that solve the run-time error you are getting and perform the scene change when the user clicks on `wejdzBtn` button.

Login.java
(I only changed the lambda expression in method `utworzBtn()`.)

```java
public class Login {
    private GridPane grid;
    private Scene scene;
    private Text title;
    private Label nick;
    private Button wejdzBtn;
    private TextField userName;

    public Login()  {
        grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(25,25,25,25));
        scene = new Scene(grid, 300, 150);
        utworzBtn();
        utworzLogin();
        utworzTekst();
        utworzNick();
    }

    private void utworzBtn() {
        wejdzBtn = new Button("Zaloguj si\u0119");
        HBox hbBtn = new HBox(10);
        hbBtn.setAlignment (Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        hbBtn.getChildren().add(wejdzBtn);
        grid.add(hbBtn, 1, 2);
        wejdzBtn.setOnAction(e -> {
            Messages mess = new Messages();
            Window w = scene.getWindow();
            if (w instanceof Stage) {
                Stage s = (Stage) w;
                s.setScene(mess.getScena());
            }
        });
    }

    private void utworzLogin() {
        nick = new Label("Nick:");
        grid.add(nick, 0, 1);
    }

    private void utworzNick() {
        userName = new TextField();
        grid.add(userName,1,1);
        userName.setPromptText("Max 15 znak\u00f3w");
        userName.setFocusTraversable(false);

        final int maxLength = 15;
        userName.setOnKeyTyped(t -> {
            if (userName.getText().length() > maxLength)
            {
                int pos = userName.getCaretPosition();
                userName.setText(userName.getText(0, maxLength));
                userName.positionCaret(pos);
            }
        });
    }

    private void utworzTekst() {
        title = new Text ("Dzień dobry!");
        title.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
        grid.add(title, 0, 0, 2, 1);
    }

    public Scene okno() {
        return scene;
    }
}
```

Messages.java
(I added method `getScena()`.)

```java
public class Messages {
    private AnchorPane anchor;
    private Scene scena;
    private Button sendBtn;
    private TextField poleDoWpisywania;
    private TextArea poleDoWyswietlania, pobierzNick;

    public Messages() {
        anchor = new AnchorPane();
        scena = new Scene(anchor, 700, 600);
        pobierzNick();
        poleDoWpisywania();
        poleDoWyswietlania();
        utworzPrzycisk();
    }

    private void utworzPrzycisk() {
        sendBtn = new Button("Wy\u015Blij");
        sendBtn.setDisable(true);
    }

    private void pobierzNick() {
        pobierzNick = new TextArea();
        pobierzNick.setEditable(false);
        pobierzNick.setWrapText(true);
    }

    private void poleDoWpisywania() {
        poleDoWpisywania = new TextField();
    }

    private void poleDoWyswietlania() {
        poleDoWyswietlania = new TextArea();
        poleDoWyswietlania.setEditable(false);
        poleDoWyswietlania.setWrapText(true);
    }

    public Scene getScena() {
        return scena;
    }

    public Pane messa() {
        return anchor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Abra, I've been thinking about it for the last 6 hours and haven't noticed this problem. I have also removed

```java
public Pane messa (); 
return anchor;
```

I do not need it ;)